# How do you clear a dropdown list box in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am using an AUTOCOMPLETEBOX defined in XAML.
I load it by having its ItemSource point to

```
private List<string> lstUserNames;
```

then, after this list is loaded I just assign the autocompletebox to the list:

```
UserNameComboBox.ItemsSource = lstUserNames;
```

so how do I clear out the AUTOCOMPLETEBOX if I want to reuse it?

I see nothing here that helps
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource` to `null` to clear it.

Comment: yep.  and then you can reassign it again